# Поиск комбинаций связей между элементами на Java

Tags: java, массивы, рекурсия, arraylist

Есть `arraylist` с несколькими массивами размером 3. В каждом из них есть номера первого и второго элементов. Например, точки на числовой оси, которые связаны связью, номер которой указан под индексом "2" в массиве.

```
0 1 0
0 1 1
0 2 2
0 2 3
1 2 4
1 2 5
1 2 6
1 2 7
2 3 8
2 3 9
```

Первый и второй столбец — номера элементов. Третий — номера узлов, соединяющих эти элементы между собой. Т.е элементы "0" и "1" связаны узлами 0 и 1. "0" и "2" узлами 2, 3 и т.д

[0,1, 4] можно расшифровать, как нулевая и первая точка на плоскости связаны "нитью" номер 4.

[image: граф]

Задача в получении листа массивов с всевозможными комбинациями узлов, начиная с первого элемента "0", заканчивая последним(в данном случае "3"), например [[0, 4, 8], [1, 4, 8] ... ]

Необходимо проследить все такие комбинации нитей от нулевой точки до последней и вывести листом листов или просто строкой. если из скриншота взять, то вот пример 048 148 248 348 058 158 258 358

Входные данные тоже представленны листом массивов [[0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1]...] как на скриншоте

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Трудность у меня заключается именно в реализации на Java с запоминанием пути, используя рекурсивный метод.

Comment: Что значит «... элементы "0" и "1" связаны узлами 0 и 1 ...». Можете создать маленький пример ввода, разобрать его от начала до конца и показать какой должен получится список на выходе?

Comment: Под вопросом есть кнопка «править». Нажав на нее, Вы сможете дополнить вопрос.

Comment: есть arraylist с несколькими массивами размером 3
в каждом из них есть номера первого и второго элементов(ну например, точки на плоскости, которые связаны связью, номер которой указан под индексом "2" в массиве. [0,1, 4] можно расшифровать, как нулевая и первая точка на плоскости связаны "нитью" номер 4

и вот так необходимо проследить все такие комбинации нитей от нулевой точки до последней и вывести листом листов или просто строкой.
если из скриншота взять, то вот пример
048
148
248
348
058
158
258
358
и тд

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Раз стоит метка «рекурсия», то можно написать поиск в глубину (псевдокод со вкусом Java):

```
/**
* point — текущая вершина
* n — количество вершин
* visited — массив, в котором отмечаются пройденные вершины
* path — текущий путь
*/ 
void findPaths(int point, int n, boolean[] visited, List<Integer> path) {
    //если дошли до последней вершины
    if(point==n-1) {
        //выводим путь
        //либо добавляем его в список путей
        //после чего возвращаемся
        return;
    }
    //иначе
    //для всех связей исходящих из point
    for(Link link : getLinks(point)) {
         //получаем следующую вершину
         int nextPoint = ...
         //и номер связи
         int linkNumber = ...
         //если вершина не посещена
         if(!visited[linkNumber]) {
              //помечаем ее как посещенную
              visited[nextPoint] = true;
              //добавляем в путь связь
              path.add(linkNumber);
              //вызываем рекурсию
              findPaths(nextPoint, n, visited, path);
              //после чего удаляем из пути связь
              path.remove(path.size()-1);
              //снимаем отметку о посещении
              visited[nextPoint] = false;
         }
    }
}
```

При первом вызове нужно передать текущую вершину — 0 и отметить ее как посещенную.

В принципе большую часть аргументов метода — количество вершин, признак посещения, текущий путь можно хранить вне метода.

Определять список связанных вершин для текущей можно по разному. Можно просто пробегаться по входному списку, можно сначала инициализировать `Map`.

Answer (score 0):

Ваши данные определяют граф (более конкретно - [мультиграф](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84)) с помощью списка рёбер.

Добавлено: ориентированный граф, судя по стрелкам в отредактированном посте.

Элементы - вершины (узлы) графа. Связи - рёбра графа.

Для того, чтобы вывести все пути от одной вершины до другой, можно выполнить процедуру, очень похожую на [обход в ширину](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D0%B2_%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83). Только пометки о прохождении должны быть не глобальными,  а влиять только на нижележащие рекурсивные вызовы.

```
FindPath(int endVertex, int curVertex, bool used[], int curPath[])
   if curVertex == endVertex
       output curPath[]
   else
      for edge in edges from curVertex
            if not used[edge]
                 FindPath(endVertex, edge.anotherVertex, used[] + edge, curPath[] + edge)
```

P.S. Кстати, проще преобразовать эту структуру в обычный граф, вставив вершины с соответствующей маркировкой в каждое ребро

Comment: да, спасибо за пояснение, я к чему-то подобному и пришел, когда пытался решить задачу. И вот проблема началась именно на последнем предложении. Пометки о прохождении, влияющие на нижележащие вызовы я не смог реализовать на Java. Поэтому взываю о помощи

Comment: Просто передавайте массив пометок (в данном случае, как я понимаю, помечаться должны рёбра, а не вершины) как аргумент функции